# Convert Entity Framework Object to JSON Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, entity-framework

I'm trying to make a generic handler post a JSONJ object based on my entity type `SYSTEM_AUDIT_SHEET`:

```
SYSTEM_AUDIT_SHEET sheet = ctx.SYSTEM_AUDIT_SHEET
                              .Where(s => s.SYSTEM_KEY == system_key_dec)
                              .Select(s => s)
                              .OrderByDescending(s => s.AUDIT_SHEET_VERSION)
                              .First();

HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(sheet));
```

But I get the following error:

> A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 
>   'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.SYSTEM_AUDIT_SHEET_521A7B786A51FC0F83641182DD72C8DFE6C082418D30BBB977B403409A74CE17'.

Why can't I convert the entity to JSON?

Comment: Create a new class similar to the object you want to serialize but without having circular reference. Fill the data in that class from sheet object and serialize it. It's a bad practice to serialize Entity Framework Object directly because of this sort of problem.

Comment: Duplicate question; answers are "use JSON.Net" which has several solutions to this problem without copy/pasting classes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606232/circular-reference-exception-with-json-serialisation-with-mvc3-and-ef4-ctp5w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot convert objects to json that reference themselves as this would create an infinitely long json string.

For example, the following pseudo-code wouldn't work because it sets up a circular reference (Dog >> Bone >> Dog...):

```
class Dog {
    private Bone myBone;
    public Dog() {
        myBone = new Bone(this);
    }
}

class Bone {
    private Dog buriedBy;
    public Bone(Dog d) {
        buriedBy = d;
    }
}
```

There seem to be some good solutions by googling 'json circular reference'.  See the top two stack overflow links.

Comment: 'Google It' is not a very helpful answer. Could you provide a link?

Comment: I provided an answer and a way of getting more material.  There were multiple links I referenced on the search page... really giving a specific google search term was the most effective way of providing the additional reference material.

Comment: Here are the links for those who need them: 1. [Json and Circular Reference Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002940/json-and-circular-reference-exception) 2. [EF 4.1 - Code First - JSON Circular Reference Serialization Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588143/ef-4-1-code-first-json-circular-reference-serialization-error) 3. [Best solution for EF 4.1 + MVC + JSON circular reference exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622430/best-solution-for-ef-4-1-mvc-json-circular-reference-exception)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that your `SYSTEM_AUDIT_SHEET` either contains a property that references instances of type `SYSTEM_AUDIT_SHEET`, or it contains a property that points to objects that have pointers to `SYSTEM_AUDIT_SHEET` instances. Serializing such a circle of pointers would result in a serialization process that would never end.

You will need to transform your `SYSTEM_AUDIT_SHEET` to a type that does not (directly or indirectly) reference itself before doing the serialization. You can create a brand new type and write code to instantiate such a type from your `SYSTEM_AUDIT_SHEET` ([AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) might come in handy here). However, I tend to find that in most cases it is easier to just use an anonymous type:

```
SYSTEM_AUDIT_SHEET sheet = /*some sheet*/
var json = new {
  sheet.Id,
  sheet.RevisionNumber,
  sheet.Title
};
return serializer.Serialize(json);
```

**EDIT**

If you want to use AutoMapper and assuming that your sheet looks something like

```
class SYSTEM_AUDIT_SHEET 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public SYSTEM_AUDIT_SHEET SomeOtherAuditSheet { get;set;}
    public string Title { get;set;}
}
```

you could create a type like

```
class JSON_SYSTEM_AUDIT_SHEET
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SomeOtherAuditSheetsId { get;set;}
    public string Title { get;set;}
}
```

When your application starts (say, in Application_Start) you configure AutoMapper:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<SYSTEM_AUDIT_SHEET, JSON_SYSTEM_AUDIT_SHEET>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.SomeOtherAuditSheetsId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SomeOtherAuditSheet.Id));
```

The `Id` and `Title` properties will be mapped directly across from `SYSTEM_AUDIT_SHEET` to `JSON_SYSTEM_AUDIT_SHEET` because they have the same names in both types. The property `SomeOtherAuditSheetsId` needs special configuration, because there is no property with that exact name on the source type.

When you want to convert SYSTEM_AUDIT_SHEET to JSON_SYSTEM_AUDIT_SHEET you do:

```
return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<SYSTEM_AUDIT_SHEET , JSON_SYSTEM_AUDIT_SHEET >(sheet);
```

You may want to have a look at [AutoMapper's flattening features](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Flattening).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yea but since there are like 30 properties i dont want to do that manually. I suppose thats what automapper is for? Could you show me how its used?

Comment: +1 for use of AutoMapper. Anyone aware of an existing tool or template that automatically duplicates a POCO for this?